# How can I paste from clipboard in serveur?

Tags: angular, click, clipboard, paste

I have an issue with my angular project, in localhost when i test my function which paste data from clipboard it's work well

**clipboard.js file** :

```
function pasteClipBoard(){}

pasteClipBoard.prototype.clipboardData = function clipboardData(textbox){

    navigator.clipboard.readText().then(

        clipText => textbox.value = clipText
    )
}
var clipboard = new pasteClipBoard()    
export {clipboard}
```

Use of my clipboard function in **.ts file** :

```
@ViewChild("keyTextbox") keyTextbox:DxTextBoxComponent

clipboardPaste($t){
    clipboard.clipboardData(this.keyTextbox)
}
```

**.html file :**

```
<dx-text-box id="textbox_paste" [(value)]="textbox" #keyTextbox width="85%"></dx-text-box>

<dx-button icon="glyphicon glyphicon-paste" hint="Paste data from clipboard" width="15%" (onClick)="clipboardPaste($event)"></dx-button>
```

But on server (IIS) it doesn't work with this error message :

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'readText' of undefined

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b1f7ou

Comment: Can you format your code properly?

Comment: can you also provide stackblitz sample of your code, like this we can easily investigate :)

Comment: @Yanis-git I edit my code do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

i have modify your code like bellow,

on your component, switch to :

```
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild("keyTextbox") keyTextbox:ElementRef // <-- should be ElementRef.

  clipboardPaste($t){
      clipboard.clipboardData(this.keyTextbox.nativeElement); // Here we provide the real HTMLElement object as parameter.
  }
}
```

then on your clipboard helper :

```
pasteClipBoard.prototype.clipboardData = textbox => {
  const el = document.createElement('textarea'); // We create temp textarea.
  el.value = textbox.value; // We populate the original values.
  el.setAttribute('readonly', ''); // we make it hidden.
  el.style.position = 'absolute';
  el.style.left = '-9999px';
  document.body.appendChild(el); // We inject it on the dom to make next line working.
  el.select(); // We select the full text.
  document.execCommand('copy'); // We ask the browser to copy the content.
  document.body.removeChild(el); // We remove from dom the temp textarea.
}
```

[you can have look on the live sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t1xzmo)

Comment: have you accepted the clipboard control from your browser ? it ask me to allow current page when i have try for the first time. Otherwise try on incognito mode

Comment: I try but nothing happens.

Comment: which browser you try ? working fine for me on chrome, firefox and safari as well

Comment: I use chrome. In your sample or doesn't work for me. Do you change something ?

Comment: not at all, just open the live sample, i am sorry i can't help you more :/